# In highcharts, is it possible get the exact position of x axis labels for overlap detection purpose?

Tags: highcharts

My data (a line chart) is dynamic, and some times the x axis label overlaps.

Customer do not want to labels in two lines or with an angle, I am wondering if it is possible to get the exacting drawing position of all the x axis labels?

Then I can loop through the labels and then find the size of each label and remove overlap ones.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get bounding box of each label. Labels are stored in `chart.xAxis[index].tick` object. Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/oe1vcmqj/4/

```
    var ticks = $('#ccontainer').highcharts().xAxis[0].ticks,
        tick, el;

    for (tick in ticks) {
        el = ticks[tick];
        console.log(
            tick, 
            ' BoundingBox: ',
            el.label.getBBox(), // bounding box
            ' X:', 
            el.label.attr('x'), // x-attribute
            ' Y:', 
            el.label.attr('y') // y-attribute
        );
    }
```